# WPF Add Row to XML Bound DataGrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

When I debug, I am unable to add a row to my DataGrid.

**Setting:** I have an XML file (C:\test.xml) that I use as my DataGrid's XmlDataProvider

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="iDraft.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="185" Width="176">

<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Name="myData" XPath="Table/ENTRY" />
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserAddRows="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text" Binding="{Binding XPath=text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Combobox">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Text="{Binding XPath=combo, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <ComboBoxItem>0</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>4</ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>                
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;

namespace iDraft
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myData.Source = new Uri(@"C:\test.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

**XML (test.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Table>
  <ENTRY>
    <text>1</text>
    <combo>1</combo>
  </ENTRY>
  <ENTRY>
    <text>2</text>
    <combo>1</combo>
  </ENTRY>
</Table>
```

I dug through some old vb.net code and found the following:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Data

Class MainWindow
 Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded

    Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("C:\test.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())

    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)

    xmlFile.Close()

    myData.Source = ds.Tables(0)

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You really should have started a new question for this EDIT.  By putting your XML into a datatable, it is no longer XML, as far as your grid is concerned so you need to remove XML dataprovider stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolution:**
I got rid of XmlDataProvider and changed XPath to Path in XAML. Other than that, my back end code stayed the same (vb.net NOT the C# code).

The only thing to note is that the binding Path has to reference the XML node names.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `myData.Source` is a URI, it is always readonly. You are going to need to put the data from the XML into another medium (classes/datatable) and handle adding/updating and saving the data back to XML format.